# Recently deleted folder empty but takes up space?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, storage

I have an Iphone XR with IOS 14.2
I emptied my recently deleted folder multiple times but it still takes up space.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you restarted your phone? How long did you wait after deleting?

Comment: yes i restarted my phone even multiple times and waited about an hour after deleting - still takes up space :(

Comment: I assume you did tap on the „Empty“ button in the first picture?

Comment: What do your settings show on the storage page?